# Python Selenium-<class 'AttributeError'> occured for - len(driver.find_Elements(locatortype,locator)) > 0

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python and developing a Selenium framework using it.

Following is the code where element.clear() and element.click() is throwing  but element.clear and element.click (without brackets are working fine)

```
def Textbox(driver,locatortype,locator,strData, strDescription):
print(locatortype,"----------",locator)
element=None
if (elementPresent(driver,locatortype,locator, 2 )== True):
    if(locatortype == By.XPATH):
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
    else:
        print("XPATH Issue")
    try:
        element.click()  #if i put element.click instead of element.click() then exception not coming.should bracket be removed?
        element.clear()  #if i put element.clear instead of element.clear() then exception not coming
    except:
         print("Exception-TextBox!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occured.")
    element.send_keys(strData)
else:
     raise FieldDisabledException

def elementPresent(driver,locatortype,locator,TimeOut):
    blnElementPresent=False
    #locatortype=By.XPATH and locator is //xpath of the element
    print("inside element present")
    print(locatortype, "----------", locator)
    try:
        driver.implicitly_Wait(10)
        #following 4 lines throws exception
        elements=driver.find_Elements(locatortype, locator)
        print("length is ",len(elements))
        blnElementPresent = (len(driver.find_Elements(locatortype,locator)) > 0)
        print(blnElementPresent)
        return blnElementPresent
    except:
        print("Exception ", sys.exc_info()[0], "occured.")
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax in the code change `find_Elements` to `find_elements`.

One more thing, you can use an `if` statement like this:

```
def elementPresent(driver,locatortype,locator,TimeOut):
    blnElementPresent=False
    #locatortype=By.XPATH and locator is //xpath of the element
    print("inside element present")
    print(locatortype, "----------", locator)
    try:
        driver.implicitly_Wait(10)
        #following 4 lines throws exception
        elements=driver.find_elements(locatortype, locator)
        print("length is ",len(elements))
        if len(driver.find_elements(locatortype,locator)) > 0:
            print(blnElementPresent)
            return blnElementPresent
        else:
            print("Exception ", sys.exc_info()[0], "occured.")
            return False
    except:
        print("Exception ", sys.exc_info()[0], "occured.")
        return False
```

**EDIT:**

The `click()` and `clear()` functions need to be called!

Here is an example of use:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="q"]')
search_element.send_keys("Hi there!!!")
print('search_element.send_keys("Hi there!!!")')
search_element.clear()
print('search_element.clear()')
search_element.send_keys("Back again")
print('search_element.send_keys("Back again")')
search_element.click()
print('search_element.click()')
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: That works.Thanks. But why element.clear() or element.click() is throwing class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException' when element.clear and element.click is wokring fine without brackets and its not throwing any exceptions?

Comment: hi @user7501425, `find_elements` returns a list... and you can't click on a list... yet if you iterate through the list or specify the index of the element then you can click...

Comment: @user7501425 if you have an example to show of the error I might be able to help...

Comment: No. Im not clicking on elements list. please see the below code.

Comment: def Textbox(driver,locatortype,locator,strData, strDescription):
    print(locatortype,"----------",locator)
    #element=None
    if (elementPresent(driver,locatortype,locator, 2 )== True):
         if(locatortype == By.XPATH):
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
         else:
             print("XPATH Issue")
         try:
             element.click()
             element.clear()
         except:
             print("Exception-TextBox!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occured.")
         element.send_keys(strData)

    else:
        raise FieldDisabledException

Comment: if i remove brackets from  click()  and clear() and keep only element.click and element.clear then Im not getting that selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'

Comment: the click() and clear() are methods that need to be called... I can't really understand the code you sent... can you edit it into the question?

Comment: Please see the edited question with the code. Please help me understand why element.click and element.clear is working but element.click() and element.clear() is throwing exception

Comment: Awesome analysis.

Comment: Thanks Moshe for taking time. But it didnt solve my problem.i was  getting the "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException"....but after maximizing the window the issue got resolved...i dont know...its quite strange..anyhow thank you so much